# Setter not consistently called in a DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Note: Rewriting as MCVE

I have a UI laid out like this whose intention is to hide a `ListView` if it's empty or show it and select the first item if it's not empty

```
<Window x:Class="BrokenSelection.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BrokenSelection"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListView.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ListView">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Style>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Set" Click="Button_Set"/>
        <Button Content="Clear" Click="Button_Clear"/>
        <Button Content="Step" Click="Button_Step"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I have a VM implemented like this

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private List<string> items = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }

        set
        {
            items = value;
            PropertyChanged?.DynamicInvoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Items"));
        }
    }
}
```

And I have codebehind like this

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Set(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var l = new List<string>();
        l.Add("Item1");
        l.Add("Item2");
        l.Add("Item3");
        l.Add("Item4");
        l.Add("Item5");

        var vm = DataContext as ViewModel;
        vm.Items = l;
    }

    private void Button_Clear(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = DataContext as ViewModel;
        vm.Items = new List<string>();
    }

    private void Button_Step(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyListView.SelectedIndex++;
    }
}
```

My problem is the `Setter` for the `SelectedIndex` succeeds as long I click "set", "clear", "set", "clear", etc...

However, if I click "set", "**step**", "clear", "set", the `SelectedIndex` ends up being -1, not 0, on the second "set". The other `Setter` does execute as the list disappears and reappears correctly. Why does manually changing the `SelectedIndex` break the setter for it in my trigger?

Comment: Well, I don't know. Sorry. Your question is much improved; thank you for that. I can easily reproduce the behavior you describe. I notice that it doesn't really matter _how_ the selection changes; if I even just click in the list view, that breaks subsequent trigger assignments. What I know: in general, explicit assignments to properties overrides style assignments (including in triggers). _Maybe_ that's what's going on here. But even adding an index property to the view model and setting the list view selected index indirectly that way doesn't solve it.

Comment: I don't have time to look harder for work-arounds. In your example above, you're directly manipulating the `SelectedIndex` property, so I guess one option is to do that elsewhere in the code-behind. There appears to be something about the list view object that, once some outside force changes the property, the trigger no longer will. But I don't know enough about the specifics to explain why or to fix the trigger setter.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. Please see my [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) below:

```cs
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _hasItems;

    public bool HasItems
    {
        get { return _hasItems; }
        set { _UpdateValue(ref _hasItems, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void _UpdateValue<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            field = newValue;
            PropertyChanged?.DynamicInvoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

            if (propertyName == nameof(HasItems))
            {
                if (HasItems)
                {
                    Items.Add("test item");
                }
                else
                {
                    Items.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO39298712SelectedIndexSetter.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO39298712SelectedIndexSetter"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:ViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding HasItems}" Content="HasItems"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=listBox1, StringFormat=SelectedIndex: {0}}"/>
    <ListView x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
      <ListView.Style>
        <p:Style TargetType="ListView">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
          <p:Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
              <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
            </DataTrigger>
          </p:Style.Triggers>
        </p:Style>
      </ListView.Style>
    </ListView>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I copied the code you provided straight into this example. All I did was add enough other code so that I had a working example that could demonstrate whether the `SelectedIndex` property did in fact change or not.

You can review the above to see if you can find what's different about your code. If you are still unable to figure out what mistake you made, please fix your question so that it includes a good MCVE like the above, but which reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: I'm not calling Add and Clear. I'm resetting the actual collection instance

Comment: Also you added `HasItems` to your VM. I'm using the `HasItems` on the `ListView` itself.

Comment: @cppguy: the `HasItems` in my VM has nothing to do with the trigger. Like I said, the style, including the trigger, is just a straight copy/paste from your post. In any case, the point here is to show a version that works. I take as granted yours is different; if a working example isn't enough to help you fix your code, you need to fix your question so it includes a good [mcve]. It still does not.

Comment: Question rewritten to be MCVE

Answer (score 0):

in advance to Peter's answer, he doesn't assign new `ObservableCollection` instance every time the collection changes, he just add/remove items from it, that is probably makes his example work (generally it is the proper way to use `ObservableCollection`, make changes to the collection itself instead of instantiate new one and assigned it).

from what you provided in your question, I suspect that the -1 value you see in the `SelectedIndex` property is caused by the assignment of empty `ObservableCollection`. as you mentioned:

> In between every assignment of the property to a new collection of 1
>   or more items, I assign it first to an empty collection (not null)

I am not 100% sure with my answer unless you will provide your code behind in a good MCVE like Peter mentioned.

Comment: I don't call `Add` on the observable collection because sometimes I have to add hundreds of items and I was concerned the UI would get hundreds of notifications to update

Comment: I understand. when you assign your SearchedResults property twice (first with empty collection then with the full one), is the SelectedIndex changes once or twice? you can check it by resgistering to the SelectionChanged event of your ListView .

Comment: The assignment to an empty collection sets it to -1. I added an EDIT2 section above which may add more color to the situation

Comment: Changed the question to be a better MCVE

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

I can reproduce the problem if I load the collection, scroll, clear, then load again, the trigger does not set the `SelectedIndex`

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top"  Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Click="Load_Button_Click">Load</Button>
            <Button Click="Clear_Button_Click">Clear</Button>
            <Button Click="Scroll_Button_Click">Scroll</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Name="SearchResultListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Email" Width="140" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ListView">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Style>
        </ListView>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    private void Clear_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<User> items = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        SearchResultListView.ItemsSource = items;
    }

    private void Load_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<User> items = new ObservableCollection<User>();

        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Smith", Age = 18, Email = "smith@test.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Joe", Age = 19, Email = "joe@test.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Walter", Age = 17, Email = "walter@test.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Tim1", Age = 44, Email = "tim1@test.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Tim2", Age = 44, Email = "tim2@test.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Tim3", Age = 44, Email = "tim3@test.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Tim4", Age = 44, Email = "tim4@test.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Tim5", Age = 44, Email = "tim5@test.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Tim6", Age = 44, Email = "tim6@test.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Tim7", Age = 44, Email = "tim7@test.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Tim8", Age = 44, Email = "tim8@test.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Tim9", Age = 44, Email = "tim9@test.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Tim10", Age = 44, Email = "tim10@test.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Tim11", Age = 44, Email = "tim11@test.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Tim12", Age = 44, Email = "tim12@test.com" });

        SearchResultListView.ItemsSource = items;
    }

    private void Scroll_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SearchResultListView.SelectedIndex < this.SearchResultListView.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            SearchResultListView.SelectedIndex++;
            SearchResultListView.ScrollIntoView(this.SearchResultListView.SelectedItem);
        }
        else 
        {
            SearchResultListView.SelectedIndex = 0;
            SearchResultListView.ScrollIntoView(this.SearchResultListView.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at my EDIT2 section. That may be what's causing the issue but still not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered the solution to this odd issue. If you set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` then the selection is not mysteriously set back to -1.